# Finding xPath containing text

Tags: xml, xpath

How would I compose and xPath that selects all records (including columns) that contain thirdcategory 'jeans'?

```
<record>
<column name="category"> <![CDATA[ Heren ]]> </column>
<column name="subcategory"> <![CDATA[ Kleding ]]> </column>
<column name="thirdcategory"> <![CDATA[ Jeans ]]> </column>
</record>
```

I know that to select I have to use:

```
/record/column[@name="thirdcategory"]
```

But how do I add 'contains "jeans"' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a help and direction of Tomalak, I found the answer:

```
/record[column[@name='thirdcategory' and contains(., 'Jeans')]]
```

Comment: Ah, well done, I've overlooked the "selects all *records*" part. Yes, that's how you would do it.

Comment: Thanks, But I can't do that in the first 2 days.. (something with my status)

Comment: No that's not about status, that's about giving other users time to provide better answers. I would have to wait the same amount of time to accept my own answers. :)

Answer (score 3):

The `.` refers to the current node, you can use it to do string comparisons.

```
/record/column[@name='thirdcategory' and contains(., 'Jeans')]
```

or this to avoid partial matches

```
/record/column[@name='thirdcategory' and normalize-space(.) = 'Jeans')]
```

Comment: That is helping a lot!
However, now I only get the column, I do need the whole record.
How to refrase?
I need all records, including all columns, but only the records that have column thirdcategory 'jeans'. (So I don't need records with thirdcategory 'somethingelse'.
Could you help me with that too?

Comment: I think I found it:
    `/record[column[@name='thirdcategory' and contains(., 'Jeans')]]`